# php, login script

Tags: php

I am new in php and I am trying to write a registration script. My problem is that when I try to sign in  and I can't see the user`s menu. Maybe the problem is with the sessions and cookies but I can't find it. Here is part of my code:

config.php

```
<?php
  oB_start(); 
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("9gag", $con);
  $logged = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * from users WHERE id='$_COOKIE[id]' AND password = '$_COOKIE[password]'"); 
  $logged = mysql_fetch_array($logged); 
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
  oB_start(); 
  include("config.php"); 
  if (!$logged[username]) { 
    if (!$_POST[login]) { 
      echo("<center><form method=\"POST\"> 
            <table> 
            <tr> 
            <td align=\"right\"> 
            User: <input type=\"text\" size=\"15\" maxlength=\"25\" name=\"username\"> 
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td align=\"right\"> 
            Password: <input type=\"password\" size=\"15\" maxlength=\"25\" name=\"password\"> 
            </td></tr><tr> 
            <td align=\"center\"> 
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"login\" value=\"Sign in\"> 
            </td></tr><tr> 
            <td align=\"center\"> 
            <a href=\"register.php\">Sign up</a> 
            </td></tr></table></form></center>"); 
    } 
    if ($_POST[login]) { 
        $username = $_POST[username]; 
        $password = $_POST[password]; 
        $info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error()); 

        $data = mysql_fetch_array($info); 
        if($data['PASSWORD'] != $password) { 
            echo "Wrong username or password!"; 
        }else{ 
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $user = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
            setcookie("id", $user['ID'],time()+(60*60*24*5), "/", ""); 
            setcookie("password", $user['PASSWORD'],time()+(60*60*24*5), "/", ""); 
        } 
    } 
} 
else { 
    echo ("<center>Welcome <b>$logged[username]</b><br /></center> 
                <a href=\"editprofile.php\">Profile</a><br /> 
                <a href=\"logout.php\">Log out</a>"); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: don't use cookies for logins. They aren't safe. You should use session variables.

Comment: Try `print_r($logged)` , it can help to find the problem , I mean - It can be the query...

Comment: So many places to begin... *twitch*... between the injection, the use of constants for array keys, the huge html echo, or even just the `<center>` tag...

Comment: Also... `mysql_select_db("9gag", $con);`    9gag?

Comment: I didn't know that to write and wrote 9gag :D About the huge html I agree.. I tried print_r method but the problem is not int the query.

Comment: if $logged would be set properly, you would get inside that last else clause then...

Answer (score 1):

How someone already said change COOCKIE With SESSION, i haven't understood very well your table/columns layout but i've tried to make better your code so try this :)

config.php

```
 <?php 
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("9gag", $con);
?>
```

login.php

```
    <?php 
  session_start();
  ob_start();
  include("config.php"); 
  if (!Isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
    if (!$_POST['login']) { 
      echo '<center><form method="POST"> 
            <table> 
            <tr> 
            <td align="right"> 
            User: <input type="text" size="15" maxlength="25" name="username"> 
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td align="right"> 
            Password: <input type="password" size="15" maxlength="25" name="password"> 
            </td></tr><tr> 
            <td align="center"> 
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign in"> 
            </td></tr><tr> 
            <td align="center"> 
            <a href="register.php">Sign up</a> 
            </td></tr></table></form></center>'; 
    } 
    if ($_POST[login]) { 
        $username = $_POST['username']; 
        $password = $_POST['password']; 
        $info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'") or die(mysql_error()); 

        $data = mysql_fetch_array($info); 
        if($data['password'] != $password) { 
            echo "Wrong username or password!"; 
        }else{ 
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $user = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
            $_SESSION['username']=$user['username'];
            $_SESSION['id']=$user['id'];
            $_SESSION['password']=$user['password'];
        } 
    } 
} 
else { 
    echo "<center>Welcome <b>".$_SESSION['username']."</b><br /></center> 
                <a href='editprofile.php'>Profile</a><br /> 
                <a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>"; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable $logged is empty in the second file so !$logged will always be true, and the first part will always execute :) Use the cookie in the second file to see if it's logged or not

Comment: Actually, because he's calling `include("config.php")`, `$logged` contains the result of the `mysql_fetch_array` call; by checking for the presence of the `username` key, he's effectively seeing if the result had any rows, which indicates if a user is logged in.